# Can I give a presentation including drawing with a pen in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have an Aquaris M10 Ubuntu edition that has a micro hdmi output. I would like to use it for giving a presentation/lecture using LibreOffice Impress or similar, but also to be able to draw on the presentation as I am giving it. Do I have any options? Ideally I'd like to just use the tablet+pen with no other peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Creation]

[image: Presentation]

[image: Penusage]

Yes it is possible,

I tested it with a Nexus 4. I logged in via the `adb shell` then I created a normal libertine cotnainer and installed libreoffice in it. 
Then I started LibreOffice Impress via the Desktop Apps Skope by tapping to the icon.

In future this complicated way will become easier. You will not need to use a command line. :-)

Well it works, but it was very slow and very stiky. You should really use a Device with a higher performance and/or wait until this feature will become more stable.

I also heard, that there are awesome plans! It will be possible in future to use the Devices Screen for the presenter's view and the presentation itself will be shown at the external screen.

Comment: Is this the answer you where looking for?